# Symfony2 - XDebug not holds on at breakpoints

Tags: symfony, xdebug, eclipse-kepler

I use Eclipse Kepler and installed symfony2 plugin from url:
http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/

Now I want to set up XDebug for the symfony webapp.

My settings:

**http-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/dev/workspace/TestProject/web"
    <Directory "C:/dev/workspace/TestProject/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My Debug Configuration in Eclipse:

(Tab: Server)
PHP Server: 
-> Base URL: http://local.dev
-> C:\dev\workspace\TestProject\web

(Tab: Debugger)
Server-Debugger: XDebug (NOT "XDebug (Symfony)")

By clicking on the bug-icon it holds on at first line. But
if I do any actions in the browser like call another page in my webapp
the breakpoint is not holding at the breakpoint in my controller.

In addition I always have to type "local.dev/app_dev.php" to start my web app? Any way to
start it by just typing "local.dev"?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you managed to setup xdebug in a plain PHP project without the symfony2 plugin being active? If not, please do so first and check if it works or not.

Comment: Works without symfony :-)

Comment: And when you activate that symfony2 plugin for the project where it does work without the plugin, does it stop working?